# Resizing UWP Window on User Drag

Tags: user-interface, resize, uwp, window

I am trying to change the size of the UI Elements within a UWP Window on the change of the size of the window itself, such as clicking the edge of the window and dragging right. However, on increase of size, there seems to be Bounds set on the creation of the Window for the maximum size of the content, is there anyway to bypass this Bounds?

Comment: Can you provide us with some xaml/code to see the issue?

Comment: Do you mean you want set the maximum of the size of the windows? If so, it seems we can not set the smallest size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the UI Element's HorizontalAlignment and/or VerticalAlignment to "Stretch". Alternatively, if you want to scale it too, you may put the whole thing in a ViewBox. There are really quite a few options to achieve what you want.

Comment: Neither of these help at all, the Alignment properties still do not actually expand the elements passed this boundary, and the ViewBox just completely removes the UI Elements from the Visible view

Comment: Be careful about where using XAML and C# together ladies and gents. Turns out I was doing foolishness and having the C# code contradict the XAML code